# Add-host or extra_host not working for windows container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

- Environment : Docker for Windows
- Container : Windows Container

In docker run command , there is --add-host option. This is not working for Windows container.

Same way there is a configuration option in a compose file , extra_host. This is also not working for windows container.

Is there any specific reason , this is not working for windows container  ?

Answer (score 5):

See docker source tree: [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/integration-cli/docker_cli_run_test.go#L1581) & [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/integration-cli/docker_cli_run_test.go#L2159):

> func (s *DockerSuite) TestRunAddHost(c *check.C) {
>       // Not applicable on Windows as it does not support --add-host
>
> func (s *DockerSuite) TestRunCreateVolumeEtc(c *check.C) {
>       // While Windows supports volumes, it does not support --add-host hence
>       // this test is not applicable on Windows.

So, I guess this is the current limit for docker for windows although I don't know why they did not support it.

And, you are not alone here, see [this discussion](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1455), and folks' suggestion is put [next](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1455#issuecomment-364430486) to Dockerfile as workaround:

```
RUN $file = $Env:windir+'\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'; `
'10.0.0.1 some.host.com' | Add-Content -PassThru $file;
```

Comment: Run script gives compile time option. Means at the time of image creation but not at the time of container creation

Comment: Yes, then, the only option maybe just add it when run with `-e`, and handle it it in entrypoint. I can't see any other solution.

Comment: I am not able to find actual implemention

Comment: In fact, I grep the sourcecode with `add-host`, I did not find the implemention either, just find the their unittest which told me it did not support windows. Maybe not in moby repo, not sure, as seems the whole projects separate to many parts now.

Comment: It would be great if the documentation at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings would mention what is not working for windows containers